# Is there a way to update a gon (ror gem) variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I know there is gon.watch functionality but it just works like a getter function but doesn't change the original object (gon variable) which I need to be updated.

So is there a way currently in which I can make an AJAX request and update a gon variable so that when I access it later in other javascript functions the updated value is reflected?

Comment: Can you specify the Gem that you're using?

Comment: https://github.com/gazay/gon/issues/56

Comment: I already saw that. If you read the thread the author says 'Gon.watch functionality works right now only like getter in JS, it don't change original object window.gon.watchedVariables.'

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

Simply add `<%= include_gon %>` as the first line of code to the partial that gets refreshed in your AJAX request.